# .net maui preview 10 doesn't single project

Tags: maui

I tried to install visual studio 2022 preview 17.1 and create new .net Maui project but it is not a single project and when I add a new page it is still Xamarin forms page and also have an error
[image]

Comment: For questions about maui, please go to https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you somehow have old templates. Open up a command-line window and run `dotnet new --install Microsoft.Maui.Templates` that should update you to the last ones, including the single project.

Comment: Great, It works perfectly. Thank you, Gerald.

Comment: Don't forget to accept it as an answer, thanks!

Comment: BTW, I had a similar problem today. Didn't have the "New Item" templates for "ContentPage (MAUI)" etc. Based on a discussion I saw somewhere, I did menu Extensions / Manage Extensions / search "MAUI". The top one was ".NET MAUI Project and Item Templates [Preview]". Installed that. That worked. So its an alternative. (I'm assuming that extension is as up-to-date as the command line approach. Which I didn't know about.)

Comment: Note that that extension is from the community and nothing official. So that is not supported by Microsoft in any way.